# Wait.Until(Expected conditions) is failing sometimes Selenium c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver

I am aware that `Thread.Sleep()` is probably not the most reliable way of waiting for an element to be displayed, clickable etc...
Therefore I've been using `Wait.Until(Expected.Conditions)` method to tell selenium webdriver to wait for an element to satisfy desired condition.

*It seems the problem is, Selenium is failing sometimes with waiting enough for an element to be displayed, clickable, etc... Even though webDriverWait is set to wait for example 15 seconds, Selenium is rushing and failing, therefore I am not getting any errors, my test passed code wise, but the actual element was clicked too early to respond on click. Is there any 100% reliable way of waiting for an element to be clickable without mistakes?*

**CODE:**

```
 //This is how I instantiate WebDriverWait
 public static readonly WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(Program.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

 //This is an example how I get and click on specific HTML element
 Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src, 'logo')]"))).Click();
```

*Any suggestions would be appreciated!*

Comment: Add a breakpoint before the click, run the script, wait for the element/page to be completely loaded... does the click work now? If not, you may be clicking the wrong element.

Comment: That's one of the first thing I have done before posting this question. Everyhting works in order, it is just now waiting enough.

Comment: What does the element HTML look like? Is there some script that runs after the page loads that modifies it in some way? Maybe the code is actually clicking the element but that element is not the one that responds to a click or maybe it's clickable but some script hasn't run that modifies it's onclick attribute or something... I'm basically grasping at straws without seeing the page. Your code looks good to do what you are asking. Selenium is identifying the element as clickable but clicking at that moment is clearly not providing the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function then do wait and find the element....this works for me always

```
public static void scrollToElement(final WebDriver webDriver, final Point location)
{
    System.out.println("Scrolling to :" +location.x +"," +location.y);
    final String sScript = "javascript:window.scrollBy("+location.x+","+location.y+")";
    final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    js.executeScript(sScript);
}
```